# Making image gallery only populate l and right instead of up and down

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, flexbox

I have follow image gallery that I am trying to turn into a slider with CSS.

[image]

As you can see it is populating the images up and down inside its outer container. I want to force it to be a certain height and then scroll. I thought by making the container `display:flexbox; overflow-x:scroll; height:100px; width:500px` that would solve that issue. However here is what it looks like if I do that:

[image]

The problem is that no matter what I do it wont scroll or overflow. It will adjust the pictures in height and width to fit inside the container. What am missing?

The code for the container and its contents:

```
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="filepath.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to have a full code example here.  What is the width of the flex container?

Comment: @peterbreen the width is unset. Happy to grab more code. What can I provide other than the width which is not set?

Comment: I was curious what was rendering.  It looks like Wais made a working example below, although I'm not sure how to get the scroll bar displaying by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet:

```css
body {
  overflow: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container li img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to have the <li> so how would I make it work like above? I set the image size and it doesnt change the output. It simply shrinks the images when I change the margin or the width of the images

Comment: It works even if you add the `<li>`. I have updated the answer.